# The (potential easter-egg) origins of Calamari Flan in The Mandalorian

Tags: star-wars, reference, doctor-who, the-mandalorian

Before "The Mandalorian" I had not heard usage of the Mon-Calamari currency known as the Flan. I am curious if there is any information that this may be an easter egg from Favreau.

As Calamari is Fish and Flan is Pudding/Custard. I wonder if this is some vague homage to Doctor Who's "Fish Fingers and Custard". Now this is obviously reaching a little. But it's not unlike Favreau to sneak in a reference like this.

Has anyone seen an interview or know if Favreau has commented on this at all?

Comment: I think you're fishing for something that's not there...

Comment: I'm looking, but can't find anything, but it is curious, since Matt Smith may or may not appear in episode IX...

Comment: I like this.  I think you are onto something.  I don't watch the Doctor, but this seems plausible.

Comment: @Luciano Yeah, I doubt there's a good hook, too.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it.

It is only in the US, and Spanish-speaking countries, that [flan means something *similar to* custard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cr%C3%A8me_caramel).

> In Spanish-speaking countries and often in the United States, flan is
>   crème caramel. This was originally a Spanish language usage, but the
>   dish is now best known in North America in a Latin American context.
>   Elsewhere, including in Britain, [a flan is a type of tart somewhat like a quiche.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flan_(pie))